# Removing a value from a binary search tree

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am writing a function that will remove an entry from a binary search tree that has a given key associated with it. So far I have this for my code:

```
template <typename Item, typename Key = Item>
bool BSTree<Item,Key>::remove(const Key& key) {
    bool removed = false;
    Node* ptr = root;
    if(ptr == NULL)
        return removed;
    while(key != ptr) {
        if(ptr == NULL)
            return removed;
        else if(key > ptr) 
            ptr = ptr->right();
        else
            ptr = ptr->left();
    }
    removed = true;
    Item max = max(ptr);
    ptr->data() = max;
    Node* prev = ptr;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->right();
    }
    delete ptr;
    if (prev->left() != NULL) 
        prev = copy(prev->left());
    delete prev;
    return removed;
}
```

Copy is another function that I have already written that will just transfer all of the values from a certain node to the end of a tree using a recursive approach. I believe that this function should work but I'm not entirely sure and was hoping to get some feedback on it.

I'm also having a problem with the last three lines of the function. In each of them, "if", "delete", and "return" are underlined and give me the error "Error: expected a declaration." I have no idea what is going on with this and would really appreciate feedback!

Comment: Do they have the same type in "while(key != ptr)"?

Comment: Yeah. By templating the function with a key, you can then check a given key against a node since the correct operators are already implemented.

Comment: I see, you are overloading the operator != to compare a Key and a Node*

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I see a couple of things.

1. For BST removal, you need a better transplant method, other than your "copy", at least you should find the next smallest node comparing to the one to be removed.
2. ptr->data() = max; I guess your "data()" method returns a reference to a member in Item. Not wrong, just feels strange.
3. You have two "delete" statements, but aren't you supposed to delete only one item?
4. In this section:

   ```
   while (ptr != NULL) {

       prev = ptr;
       ptr = ptr->right();
   }
   delete ptr;
   ```

   After the while exits, the value of ptr is NULL, so you are deleting a NULL, not cool.